# mql4 separate window indicator using sin wave function

Tags: mql4

Below is the original code that creates a sin wave in a separate window for MetaTrader 4. My question is how to code it for a 2nd, or 3rd sin wave. The original code is compiled and is functional. I will also attach the code I added to the original, it still creates the 1st sin wave but not the second wave. I need help coding the 2nd and 3rd waves. Thanks.

This is the original working code:

```
//---- indicator settings
#property indicator_separate_window
#property indicator_buffers 2 // org 1
#property indicator_color1 Red //

//---- indicator buffers
double ExtBuffer1[];
double Dgr[];
extern datetime StartTime=D'1999.11.10 00:00';

//+---------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function |
//+---------------------------------------------------------------+
int init()
{
IndicatorBuffers(1);
SetIndexStyle(0,DRAW_LINE); // 0
SetLevelValue(0,0); //
//----indicator buffers mapping //
SetIndexBuffer(0,ExtBuffer1);
SetIndexShift(0,25); // B. added
//---- initialization done
return(0);
}
//+---------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Accelerator/Decelerator Oscillator |
//+---------------------------------------------------------------+
int start()
{
int Shift;
int i;
Shift=iBarShift(Symbol(),PERIOD_D1,StartTime); // Only run on PERIOD_D1
ArrayResize(Dgr,Shift+1); // ArrayResize(Dgr,Shift+1); ?????????????????
MyCalc(Shift,1); // ??? 1
for(i=Shift; i>=0; i--)
ExtBuffer1[i]=Dgr[i];

return(0);
}
//+---------------------------------------------------------------+
void MyCalc(int Shift,int i Yhigh)
{
int i;
for(i=Shift;i>=0;i--) // should be >
{
Dgr[i]=i*2.5;
// ..... B. added code below
double val=i*2.5; // 2.5

Dgr[i]=MathSin(3.14159*val/149)+Yhigh; // 149 ,,, Origina code ... 
Dgr[i]=MathSin(3.14159*val/180)+Yhigh; changing the /180 to lower degree changes the 
frequency
// ..... B. added above code
//Dgr[i]=MathSin(3.14159*Dgr[i]/180)+Yhigh; // Original Dgr[i]=MathSin(3.14159*- 
Dgr[i]/180)+Yhigh;
}
}
```

This code below is the same code, but with my attempt at creating the 2nd sin wave code added to the original code.

```
//---- indicator settings
#property indicator_separate_window
#property indicator_buffers 2 // org 1
#property indicator_color1 Red //
#property indicator_color2 Orange //



//---- indicator buffers

double ExtBuffer1[];
double ExtBuffer2[];

double Dgr[];
double Dgr2[];

extern datetime StartTime=D'1999.11.10 00:00';


//+---------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function |
//+---------------------------------------------------------------+
int init()
{
IndicatorBuffers(2);
SetIndexStyle(0,DRAW_LINE); // 0
SetIndexStyle(1,DRAW_LINE); // 0

SetLevelValue(0,0); //

//----indicator buffers mapping //

SetIndexBuffer(0,ExtBuffer1);
SetIndexBuffer(1,ExtBuffer2);

SetIndexShift(0,25); // B. added
SetIndexShift(1,25); // B. added

//---- initialization done
return(0);
}
//+---------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Accelerator/Decelerator Oscillator |
//+---------------------------------------------------------------+
int start()
{
int Shift;
int i;

Shift=iBarShift(Symbol(),PERIOD_D1,StartTime); // Only run on PERIOD_D1
ArrayResize(Dgr,Shift+1); // ArrayResize(Dgr,Shift+1); ?????????????????
ArrayResize(Dgr2,Shift+1);

MyCalc(Shift,1); // ??? 1
for(i=Shift; i>=0; i--)
ExtBuffer1[i]=Dgr[i];
ExtBuffer2[i]=Dgr2[i];


return(0);
}
//+---------------------------------------------------------------+

void MyCalc(int Shift, int Yhigh)
{
int i;

for(i=Shift;i>=0;i--) // should be >
{
Dgr[i]=i*2.5;
Dgr2[i]=i*2.5;


double val=i*2.5; // 2.5
double val2=i*2.5; // 2.5

Dgr[i]=MathSin(3.14159*val/149)+Yhigh; // 149
Dgr2[i]=MathSin(3.14159*val2/49)+Yhigh; // 49

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just mixed up some lines of your code. Try the following.

```
//---- indicator settings
#property indicator_separate_window
#property indicator_buffers 4
#property indicator_color1 Red
#property indicator_color2 Orange

//---- indicator buffers
double ExtBuffer1[], ExtBuffer2[];
double Dgr1[], Dgr2[];
extern datetime StartTime=D'1999.11.10 00:00';

//+---------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function |
//+---------------------------------------------------------------+
int init()
{
   IndicatorBuffers(2);
   SetIndexStyle(0,DRAW_LINE); SetIndexBuffer(0,ExtBuffer1); SetIndexShift(0,25);
   SetIndexStyle(1,DRAW_LINE); SetIndexBuffer(1,ExtBuffer2); SetIndexShift(1,25);
   SetLevelValue(0,0);
return(0);
}
//+---------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Accelerator/Decelerator Oscillator |
//+---------------------------------------------------------------+
int start()
{
   int Shift;
   int i;
   Shift=iBarShift(Symbol(),PERIOD_D1,StartTime);
   ArrayResize(Dgr1,Shift+1); ArrayResize(Dgr2,Shift+1);
   MyCalc(Shift,1);
   for(i=Shift; i>=0; i--)
   {
      ExtBuffer1[i]=Dgr1[i];
      ExtBuffer2[i]=Dgr2[i];
   }
return(0);
}
//+---------------------------------------------------------------+
void MyCalc(int Shift,int Yhigh)
{
   int i;
   for(i=Shift;i>=0;i--)
   {
      Dgr1[i]=i*2.5; Dgr2[i]=i*2.5; 
      double val1=i*2.5;
      double val2=i*2.5;
      Dgr1[i]=MathSin(3.14159*val1/149)+Yhigh;
      Dgr2[i]=MathSin(3.14159*val2/49)+Yhigh;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Paul B. for your response and answer. I will mark your answer as the correct answer, There is one other thing that needs to be fixed. As the code now stands it keeps the sin waves stationary. The sin waves do not shift to the left with the candles when new candles are formed. Would there be a simple fix to this? if not, do not worry about it. Thank you very much for your response and answer.

Comment: The indicator is only set to change daily (look at the Shift statement, it's set to PERIOD_D1). If could probably do with rewriting a bit is you want the indicator to shift at the open of each new bar.

Comment: So if I wanted to use the indicator on the 1 hour chart I would just change this ... Shift=iBarShift(Symbol(),PERIOD_D1,StartTime); to Shift=iBarShift(Symbol(),PERIOD_H1,StartTime); or Shift=iBarShift(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,StartTime); ... ?                                         
Yes I would need it to shift at the open of each new bar.

Comment: That "should" work, but personally I'd reprogram it using a more robust and less resource intensive method. Have a go, if you get stuck, post another question.